# 'Rel' tag inside a Map?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have a section of a mapped image that I would like to initiate a gallery (Pretty Photo plugin). However, it looks like the 'area' tag doesn't support the 'rel' attribute? Unfortunately that's the only way for me to initiate the gallery. I attached my attempt (was unsuccessful) below. Any suggestions?

```
 <area shape="rect" coords="32,567,435,810" href="images/gallery_01.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="Preview" />
```

Comment: When you say, "doesn't support" are you referring to a strict XHTML schema?  Can you use a looser definition?

Comment: @jbrookover: it doesnt work haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just using rectangular coordinates on the image map, instead you can overlay an a tag, which supports rel, in that same location using positioning:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="your_image_map.jpg" />
  <a href="images/gallery_01.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="Preview"> </a>
</div>

#wrapper { position:relative; }
#wrapper a {
  width:403px; height:243px;
  position:absolute; left:32px; top:567px;
}
```

Comment: actually that didn't work - I have a wrapper set up that centers the content (width: 960px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto) and the new link is doing weird things with absolute positioning. Any help here?

Comment: You have to set `position:relative` on your wrapper.  Without seeing code I can't help other than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prettyPhoto API to open content from image maps.

You code would look something like:

```
 <area shape="rect" coords="32,567,435,810" href="images/gallery_01.jpg" onclick="$.prettyPhoto.open('path/to/your/image.jpg','Title','Description'); return false" title="Preview" />
```

Complete documentation can be found here: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

I found something that may be of use to you all.  THis is what I did to open an external link in a div

```
<div class="whatever"  href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$.prettyPhoto.open('http://whatever');">
</div>
```

You can see the results here http://fbc.net and click on 'serve'

Comment: That's awesome! So simple too, I didn't know you could make an entire DIV a link